# FileNotFoundError in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pdflatex

I try to convert latex file to pdf with python programming in Google Colab, but throw filenotfounderror.

my code is:

```
import pdflatex as ptex

pdfl = ptex.PDFLaTeX.from_texfile(r'cv_7.tex')
pdf, log, completed_process = pdfl.create_pdf()
with open('testPDF4.pdf', 'wb') as pdfout:
        pdfout.write(pdf)
```

error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-a8655500d33f> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 pdfl = ptex.PDFLaTeX.from_texfile(media)
      6 # pdfl = ptex.PDFLaTeX.from_texfile(r'cv_7.tex')
----> 7 pdf, log, completed_process = pdfl.create_pdf()
      8 with open('testPDF4.pdf', 'wb') as pdfout:
      9         pdfout.write(pdf)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pdflatex/pdflatex.py in create_pdf(self, keep_pdf_file, keep_log_file, env)
     75             args = self.get_run_args()
     76             fp = subprocess.run(args, input=self.latex, env=env, timeout=15, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
---> 77             with open(os.path.join(td, 'file.pdf'), 'rb') as f:
     78                 self.pdf = f.read()
     79             with open(os.path.join(td, 'file.log'), 'rb') as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpvx0f0axf/file.pdf'
```

Comment: That `pdflatex` package looks like abandonware - no release in 4.5 years, and the Github repo has been deleted.

Comment: which package is useful instead of pdflatex?